# Connection Failure with CFHTTP

Tags: coldfusion

I have a call to an api I am making. It sometimes works, but sometimes does not work. It is throwing a parsing error "Message: JSON parsing failure at character 1:'C' in Connection Failure". I am taking this to mean that I am sending the request, I am being returned a connection failure message, and I am trying to parse that as if it were the data set and it is erroring out. Is that correct?

If the person hits the back button and processed the request again it goes through. So it is randomly returning that. I am running this app on 23 machines and there are many calls to this api per minute. I am trying to find out if this could be something on my side or on the api side.

Any info or suggestions is appreciated.

```
<cfhttp result="result" method="get" charset="utf-8" url="#url#" username="#uname#" 
password="#pw#">
</cfhttp>

<cfset content = #result.Filecontent#> 
<cfset data = #DeserializeJSON(content)#>
```

Here is what is returned with the connection failure.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Coldfusion are you on?

Comment: CF 2018 Enterprise.

Comment: Don't know the cause of the error, but the code should always check the response status code first, before attempting to deserialize, sinve it might not return json. Start by dumpting the cfhhtp response and see if there are any other details about the error

Comment: I have updated my post and included the dump. It just says peer not authenticated. If I hit refresh it goes though fine. Is there a way to tell cfhhtp to try again if it gets this connection failure?

Comment: ---> https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/getting-sporadic-quot-i-o-exception-peer-not-authenticated-quot-error-using-cfhttp/m-p/11252628